# iflang Warning: Mismatch between \language (patterns) and and setting of \languagename

Tags: languages

I am currently writing a class and there I need to test the current language.
Therefore I use the package `iflang`. A strange warning pops up when I change
the default language, consider:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{iflang}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\noindent PATT: \the\l@dutch \\
LANG: \the\language
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

The code does not produce any warnings, but if I change the code to `\setdefaultlanguage{dutch}`, the package `iflang` produces a warning:

```
Package iflang Warning: Mismatch between \language (patterns)
(iflang)                and setting of \languagename.
```

despite the two variables having the same value. Is this a bug in the
package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{dutch}
```

the language name is `dutch`, but the language setting is still the default language 0 (USenglish). Thus the warning is correct. Package `polyglossia` sets the language later in `\begin{document}`.

The warning can be avoided:

- Loading the package later, when `polyglossia` has set the language:

  ```
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage{dutch}
  \AtBeginDocument{\usepackage{iflang}}
  ```
- Or explicit setting of the language:

  ```
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlangauge{dutch}
  \selectlanguage{dutch}
  \usepackage{iflang}
  ```
- Or loading package `iflang` earlier:

  ```
  \usepackage{iflang}
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \setdefaultlanguage{dutch}
  ```