# Beamer: Package iflang Warning: Mismatch between \language (patterns) (iflang) and setting of \languagename

Tags: beamer, babel, languages

When loading the iflang package in a beamer presentation I get the warning
*Package iflang Warning: Mismatch between \language (patterns) (iflang) and setting of \languagename*.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{iflang}

\begin{document}
    content...
\end{document}
```

This warning occurs regardless of whether I load the babel package or pass the language as class option as well.

If I change the document class from beamer to article I do *not* get this warning regardless of whether I load the babel package or pass the language as class option.

A [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/249087/120953) regarding this warning has been asked before, there however in the context of the article class (where I do not get this warning) and not in the context of pdflatex (because the polyglossia package was used).
I have tried the three ways in the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249098/120953) but I was unable to avoid the warning with any of them.

The beamer documentation section 2.6 *Compatibility with Other Packages and Classes* does *not* mention the iflang package.

I am using beamer 2013/12/02 3.33 and pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.4.22).

Does this warning do any harm?
How can I avoid it using the beamer class?

Comment: Just as information: I also get this warning with an up to date texlive2017.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in `iflang`, which relies on `\uselanguage` being defined for distinguishing between a format based on `language.dat` (essentially LaTeX in various engine dependent flavors) or on `etex.src` (essentially plain TeX based formats).

If `\uselanguage` is defined, `iflang` assumes the latter kind of format. However, `beamer` *does* define `\uselanguage`, so the final test performed by the package fails and, most likely, also other tests.

I made a test and changed line 196 of `iflang.sty` (v. 1.6, released 2016/05/16) from

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname uselanguage\endcsname\relax
```

into

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname et@xpatterns\endcsname\relax
```

and the tests work as expected. The macro `\et@xpatterns` is most likely only defined in `etex.src`.

As a (hopefully temporary) workaround, you can fix manually the wrong setup:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{iflang}

\makeatletter
\def\IfLang@prefix{l@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    content...
\end{document}
```

but you have to live with the spurious warning.

Comment: Filed issue report: https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/33

Comment: fixed at souce https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek